# Using Public Resource from another bundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have tried searching for similar questions in Google but seems I can't find one. I create new bundle and about 80 % Public Resources (CSS, images, JavaScript, etc) is same. Is it right to use another Public Resources from another bundle or is there any other suggestions in Symfony2 Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are varying opinions here, but I'd say **yes**, you can. Just make sure you declare the dependencies in your `composer.json`.

The second bundle should declare the first one as a required [dependency](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/doc/04-schema.md#package-links). This of course is assuming that you're building each bundle standalone. If they're all just part of one big project, you probably wont need to do this.

Comment: Its in 1 project. My bundle is look like this /sifo/AdminBundle /sifo/UserBundle/ and /sifo/PublicBundle . I wanna use just 1 place for Assets (AdminBundle). Is there any referrence for this case? I try to search in google but cant find one. Thank you.

Comment: I do something similar. I use a `CommonBundle` where shared assets like icons, images and JS (like jQuery) go into.